# Prove relation between Lucas and Fibonacci numbers using tilings

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

I struggle a lot with combinatorial proofs and was hoping for some help. I need to prove by strong induction that $L_n = F_{n-2} + F_n$ and how this shows that $L_n$ counts the tilings of the circular $n$-board with $1$- and $2$-tiles

EDIT ANSWER: Source is Proofs that Really Count: The Art of Combinatorial Proof
 By Arthur T. Benjamin, Jennifer J. Quinn

[Lucas Numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQcxo.png)

Comment: What have you tried? What recursion holds for $L_n$? Andwhat for $F_n$? Does the claim hold for a few small $n$?

Comment: I guess I could fumble my way through a proof of Ln holding true I guess I can't really wrap my head around what that has to do with tiles on a circular board.

Comment: Some proofs write themselves. Suppose we know that for a specific $k$, we know that $L_k=F_k+E_{k-2}$ **and** $L_{k+1}=F_{k+1}+F_{k-1}$. What can we conclude about $L_{k+2}$?

Comment: Ah, it would be Lk = Fk+2 + Fk, i'm also guessing the + 2 accounts for the 2 tilings and the k for the regular tilings?

Comment: About tiles on a circular board, have you done, in class or as part of earlier homework, a problem about expressing $n$ as a sum of $1$'s and/or $2$'s? Or something similar? Fibonacci numbers come up. And yes, you "add" the two equations I gave, then it is one sentence more.

Comment: We haven't done anything with tiles in the class yet, this is my first experience with this and representing Lucas numbers as a form of Fibonacci numbers

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15648/lucas-numbers-and-tilings?

Comment: Yes it is! Thank you! I found the identity in the mentioned book and will edit it into my original post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The induction argument is very straightforward. For the combinatorial part, label the cells of the circular $n$-board $1,2,\dots,n$, and consider any tiling of that board. There are two possibilities: there is a tile occupying cells $n$ and $1$, or there is no such tile. If there is no such tile, you can break the tiling open between cells $n$ and $1$ to get a tiling of an $n$-strip. If there is such a tile, break the tiling open between cells $n-1$ and $n$ and between $1$ and $2$ to get a tiling of the $(n-2)$-strip.